# Augmenting 2D array value crashes program

Tags: c, arrays

I'm creating a letter frequency counter in C that keeps track of how many times a character is used in a given string. A 2d array keeps track of the data while the program loops through each character:

```
char* input = "The cat jumped over the fence";
int inputlength = (int) strlen(input);

//keeps track of how many times each character is used
int letterfrequencies[26][2] = {
    {'a',0},
    {'b',0},
    {'c',0},
    {'d',0},
    {'e',0},
    {'f',0},
    {'g',0},
    {'h',0},
    {'i',0},
    {'j',0},
    {'k',0},
    {'l',0},
    {'m',0},
    {'n',0},
    {'o',0},
    {'p',0},
    {'q',0},
    {'r',0},
    {'s',0},
    {'t',0},
    {'u',0},
    {'v',0},
    {'w',0},
    {'x',0},
    {'y',0},
    {'z',0}
};
int currentchar=0;
int letternum=0; //character position in char counting array
for (int i=0; i<inputlength; i++) {
    currentchar=input[i];
    letternum=0;
    while (currentchar!=letterfrequencies[letternum][0]) {
        letternum++;
    }
    printf(" Found a character ");
    letterfrequencies[letternum][1]++; //Add to char counting array
    printf("\n");
}
```

On the first iteration of the loop (I'm using the xCode debugger with break points), everything works as expected. However, after the first iteration, the line:

```
letterfrequencies[letternum][1]++;
```

crashes the program, saying Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7fff5fc2e84c). If I comment the line out, everything runs through without an issue.
What could be causing this?

Comment: Think what happens when `currentchar` is a space. Your code invokes undefined behavior. You should take some action if `currentchar` is not found in `letterfrequencies`

Comment: @Cool Guy that fixes it.

Comment: the posted code will fail in a real world scenario where the input data contain capitals, punctuation, space, or any char value not in the range a...z.  Suggest: make the table 256 entries and only a int counter.  Then increment a count by letterFrequencies[input[x]]++;   This results in a one statement update, no searching with possibility/probability of running off the end of the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The input sentence contain both upper- and lower-case letters, as well as spaces, but your `letterfrequencies` array only contain lower-case letters. So think about what would happen when you have an upper-case letter or a space and search for it, it won't be found so the `while` will just continue and go out of bounds of your array leading to *undefined behavior*.

Use the `isspace` function to check for spaces, and use `tolower` convert capical letters to lower-case letters.

Answer (score 2):

The problem rises when you handle the space character, you should check if the character is a (lowercase) letter.

---

As a side note, you don't need a 2-d array to store the frequencey of letters. Instead, use:

```
int letterfrequencies[26] = {0};
```

Assuming the letter is `currentchar`, increment `letterfrequencies[currentchar - 'a']`. For instance, if the letter is `'z'`, `letterfrequencies[25]` is incremented because `'z' - 'a'` is `25`.

Answer (score 0):

Variable letternum is bigger than 25... becouse you have for example ´T´ in the input and then you are comparing in the while loop chars...so it is changing chars onto code so it looks like `while(84 == 97)` and so on. In ascii code there are codes for small and capital letters.

And also you don't have space there '' there is an error at most.